# Advanced count association broken after sequel upgrade

Tags: ruby, sequel

I created an association in order to reduce the number of queries in a construct like this

```
@user.all do |user|
  puts "User ##{user.id}, post count: #{user.posts_count}"
end
```

My Model:

```
class User
 one_to_many :posts
 one_to_one :posts_count, :read_only => true, :key => :id,
    :dataset => proc{Post.where(:user_id => :id, :deleted => false).select{count(Sequel.lit("*")).as(count)}},
    :eager_loader => (proc do |eo|
      eo[:rows].each{|p| p.associations[:posts_count] = nil}
      Post.where(:user_id => eo[:id_map].keys, :deleted => false).
        select_group(:user_id).
        select_append{count(Sequel.lit("*")).as(count)}.
        all do |t|
          p = eo[:id_map][t.values.delete(:user_id)].first
          p.associations[:posts_count] = t
        end
      end)

  def posts_count
    super.try(:[], :count) || 0
  end

  # ...
end
```

After upgrading to sequel 4.1.0 I get `unitialized constant PostsCount`, while in sequel 3.44 it worked fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a class attribute solves the issue. Include `:class => "Post"` like this:

```
one_to_one :posts_count, :read_only => true, :key => :id, :class => "Post",
#...
```